# What is the Javassist version that is compatible with Hibernate 4.3.1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, configuration, java-bytecode-asm

I've been working on a project and using Hibernate 4.3.1, and an error popped up.

After searching for what the error meant, I found out that its caused by a version incompatibility between Hibernate and Javassist.

So, what version of Javassist is compatible with Hibernate 4.3.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate 4.3.1 uses the following `javassist` framework version:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
  <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
  <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```